# What is the most common Nonparametric Global Test of Difference for Repeated Measure?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, repeated-measures, post-hoc, friedman-test

The experiment goes like, there are two different machines, Machine_A and Machine_B and a Technician. The machines have the same purpose which is for measuring a continuous quantity (be it weight, temperature, or anything) and the Technician is supposed to be like the one with the correct measurements. The researcher wants to study which of the machines is better. So same sample materials are tested on each machines and by the technician. The time it takes for each machine to process each sample is also recorded.

So I have five columns, 3 for the measurements of Machine A, Machine B and the Technician and 2 for the processing time of each machine.  I used `shapiro.test()` and got `p<0.05` for all columns so I did Friedman's Test followed by Conover's Test via the `PMCMRplus` package but I encountered problems like a significant global test but all post-hoc available in package couldn't detect any significant pairs. I notice this pattern occurs when the p-value for my global test is just a few points shy away from `0.0500`.

1. Are my choice of statistical tests correct?
2. Is a nonsignificant post-hoc after a significant global test an indicator inappropriate  post-hoc test? If not, what is the reason?
3. What is the alternative to Friedman's Test? (Repeated Measure Global Test of Difference) I found ART-ANOVA but I'm not sure.